# How to pass table values parameter using dynamic query in SQL server 2008

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am calling one function using dynamic SQL query which accepts TVP. Is there any way to pass table values parameter in dynamic sql. One thing I can do to achieve this is to pass comma separated string and then convert this comma separated string to table. But the problem is then I have to convert string - table for each item in my table (The function is called for all the rows) which can be avoided if I can pass table in dynamic sql.

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: Passing an XML document is an option to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. Where `inputTable` is your TVP type and `@test` is the variable:

```
exec sp_executesql
 N'select
    t.*
   from @test as t
   where t.ID = 2'
,N'@test inputTable readonly' -- note the readonly
,@test
```